# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Trying to add FK constraint, getting error: "Invalid column..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint to link my tables, however I keep getting this error:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Foreign key 'fk_customers_titles' references invalid column 'title_id' in referencing table 'customers'.

I've created my tables, along with it's columns and also stated my primary keys using the `ALTER TABLE` statement. But whenever I try to add a foreign key constraint for any table, I keep getting this error.

This is how I created my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
 customer_id    char_idtype,
 name           varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
 contact_name   varchar(30),
 address        varchar(50),
 city           varchar(20),
 region         varchar(15),
 country_code   varchar(10),
 country        varchar(15),
 phone          varchar(20),
 fax            varchar(20)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE titles
(
 title_id       char(3)         NOT NULL,
 description    varchar(35)     NOT NULL
);
GO
```

And this is how I added my primary keys:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);
GO

ALTER TABLE titles
ADD PRIMARY KEY (title_id);
GO
```

This is how I am adding my foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_customers_titles 
FOREIGN KEY (title_id)
REFERENCES titles(title_id);
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Your help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear:  `customers` does not have a `title_id`.  You need to add it . . .

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD title_id       char(3);
```

Or put it in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be like below mentioned.

```
CREATE TABLE titles
(
 title_id       char(3)      Primary key   NOT NULL,
 description    varchar(35)     NOT NULL
);
GO




CREATE TABLE customers
(
 customer_id     char(3) primary key, 
 title_id       char(3)     foreign key references titles,
 name           varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
 contact_name   varchar(30),
 address        varchar(50),
 city           varchar(20),
 region         varchar(15),
 country_code   varchar(10),
 country        varchar(15),
 phone          varchar(20),
 fax            varchar(20)
);
GO
```